# Ubuntu maverick username and password works with ssh but not with smb when I connect from MacOS 10.6.5

Tags: macos, ubuntu, samba

I have an Ubuntu Maverick desktop that I can easily connect using ssh but when I want to see the shared directories using "go to server", MacOs connects to the Ubuntu machine and I can see the shared directories but when I enter my username@ubuntu_machine and password to get access it complains about me entering wrong username and/or password.
Any ideas? What more information would you need to give me some advise? Is there a step by step how-to manual to get this done?
thanks

edited the question based on John T's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to see if the passwords match as ssh uses the system password but Samba has it's own authentication system.

You can set your samba password with the `smbpasswd` command to double check. In the past I've had to do `smbpasswd -a myusername` for it to work.

- [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/smbpasswd.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

The smb dialog is probably prepending the name of your Mac machine to the login. Try changing it to the name of the smb server using this format:

`ubuntu-box\username`

or

`username@ubuntu-box`

Comment: nope, I tried it but that's not it. Thanks for the answer though.